# Como fazer uma classe de controle para o crud do JDBC

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, crud

- Como faço uma classe de controle para um método listar do meu crud?
- O método da minha classe dao irá retornar todos os dados setados que
  tiverem a mesma cidade.
- Mas acontece este erro na minha classe main:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
***Método da classe Dao***

> ```
> public List<ViagemBean> getListaDestino(String nomeCidade) {
>       try {
>           List<ViagemBean> viagens = new ArrayList<ViagemBean>();
>
>           ConexaoMySQL.conectar();
>
>           PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMySQL.getConexao()
>                   .prepareStatement("select * from viagem where cidade = ? ");
>
>              stmt.setString(1, nomeCidade);  
>
>           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
>
>           while (rs.next()) {
>               // criando o objeto viagem
>               ViagemBean viagem = new ViagemBean();
>               viagem.setIdViagem(rs.getInt("idViagem"));
>               viagem.setTipo(rs.getString("tipoViagem"));
>
>               Calendar dataInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
>               dataInicio.setTime(rs.getDate("dataInicio"));
>               viagem.setDataInicio(dataInicio);
>
>               Calendar dataF = Calendar.getInstance();
>               dataF.setTime(rs.getDate("dataEncerramento"));
>               viagem.setDataEncerramento(dataF);
>
>               viagem.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
>               viagem.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
>               viagem.setValorDiaria(rs.getDouble("valorDiaria"));
>               viagem.setColaborador(rs.getString("colaborador"));
>               viagem.setCliente(rs.getString("cliente"));
>
>               // adicionando o objeto à lista
>               viagens.add(viagem);
>           }
>           rs.close();
>           stmt.close();
>           return viagens;
>       } catch (SQLException e) {
>           throw new RuntimeException(e);
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

***Método da Classe controle***

> ```
> package controle;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> import modelo.ViagemBean;
> import modelo.ViagemDao;
>
> public class Controle {
>
>
>    public static List<ViagemBean> getListaViagensPorString(String nomeCidade) { 
>        return new ViagemDao().getListaDestino(nomeCidade); }
>
>
>
>
> }
> ```

***Método da classe MAIN***

> ```
> private static void listarViagemDestino() {
>       ViagemDao dao = new ViagemDao();
>
>       Controle controle = new Controle();
>
>
>       String nomeCidade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome de uma cidade:");
>
>       List<ViagemBean> viagens = controle.getListaViagensPorString(nomeCidade);
>
>       for (ViagemBean contato : viagens) {
>
>
>
>           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
>                   ("IdViagem: " + contato.getIdViagem()+ "\n")
>                   +("tipo: " + contato.getTipo()+ "\n")
>                   +"Data de inicio: " + contato.getDataInicio().getTime() + "\n"
>                   +("Data de fim: " + contato.getDataEncerramento().getTime() + "\n"
>                   +("cidade: " + contato.getCidade()+ "\n")
>                   +("uf: " + contato.getUf()+ "\n")
>                   +("valor da diaria: " + contato.getValorDiaria()+ "\n")
>                   +("colaborador: " + contato.getColaborador()+ "\n")
>                   +("cliente: " + contato.getCliente()+ "\n")));
>
>
>       }
>
>
>
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu vi o seguinte erro no seu main você esta chamando:

```
 Controle.getListaViagens("cidade", JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome de uma cidade:"));
```

porém o método do seu controle não recebe parâmetros, você esta tentando mandar duas Strings como parâmetros:

```
public List<ViagemBean> getListaViagens() {
  return new ViagemDao().getListaDestino();}
```

A mensagem de erro já te diz qual é o problema.

Comment: A minha duvida é, que parâmetro eu preciso passar para o controle ?

Comment: Pelo seu código não é necessário enviar nenhum parâmetro. Você que fazer um método que receba o nome da cidade e pesquisa por ela. Mas o jeito que você fez para pegar essa String está errado.

Comment: O usuário irá inserir o nome da cidade e então aparecerá todas as viagens  que tenham essa mesma cidade.

Comment: Mude o método public List<ViagemBean> getListaDestino() {} para public List<ViagemBean> getListaDestino(String nomeCidade) {}, E crie outro método no seu Controlador  public List<ViagemBean> getListaViagensPorString(String nomeCidade) {
      return new ViagemDao().getListaDestino(nomeCidade);
  }

Comment: Cara o compilador diz que o método getListaViagensPorString(String) no controle não é aplicável para os argumentos () ????

Comment: Daí pede para adicionar um argumento no   List<ViagemBean> viagens = controle.getListaViagensPorString(); <<< mas que argumento seria esse ????

Comment: Esse argumento é o nome da cidade que você quer passar, no seu caso vai ser o nome que o usuário informar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25502/discussion-between-jarwin-and-rafael-ferreira).